# android: Create a new folder on a server using php

Tags: php, android, directory

I am writing an Android application where I am uploading files to a server, but I would like to find a way how to create a new folder on a server, to which the files would be uploaded instead.

I need the folder to be created programatically in the application, as every user of the app would have his own folder on the server, which would be created during the first upload of a file.

Could someone please give me an advice how to do that?

This is my php script so far:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";

$new_dir_name = $_GET['myDirectory'];
$file_path .= $new_dir_name . '/';

if (!is_dir($file_path)) {
        mkdir($file_path);
    chmod($file_path, 0777);
}

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

And this is the code in my app to connect to it:

```
            //updated:

            String myDirectory = "nameofNewDir";
        upLoadServerUri = "myserver/upload.php"+"?myDirectory="+myDirectory;  

filePathOnServer = "http://users.ecs.soton.ac.uk/du1e11/uploads/"+myDirectory+"/";



        URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=uploaded_file;filename= '"
                    + fileName + "'" + lineEnd);
```

Comment: I'd start with this thought: the Android app would initiate some request to some secured server URL, and PHP running on the server at that URL will create the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you should have a writeable base directory where PHP would be able to create subfolders. Then in your upload server-side script use an mkdir() command and chmod() to create and set permissions to the directory accordingly, then move the uploaded file to that folder. When you upload the file via your android app, the folder will be automatically created and the file will be moved there.

Here's the code for your particular case:

```
<?php

    $file_path = "uploads/";
    $new_name = "new_folder"; // this is the new folder you'll create
    $file_path .= $new_name . '/';
    mkdir($file_path);
    chmod($file_path, 0777);

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

In your question you say you don't know the name of the folder to create. Well, this should be done on PHP side. You should decide on the server what name of the folder to use. In your original code there is nothing that specifies the folder, so it's up to you to decide how you want to do it.

Comment: I have one script in the directory on the server already for uplading. I am not very experienced in php, could you provide me of a bit of a code for it, if possible? :)

Comment: Without knowing your particular situation i can only provide some pseudo code. Hope you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: I have updated my question with an actual code from my app

Comment: Updated my answer. Although you'll have to find a way to know what the name of the folder should be. As soon as you do that, you'll be able to use my sample code to make it work.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me, and i found out how to pass the name of a new directory from the app to the script by GET request. Now, a new directory specified in the app is created, the problem now is that even though the new dir is created, the file is still being uploaded to the "uploads/" directory, instead of the newly created one. And unfortunately I cant see anything wrong with the code now :/

Comment: When in doubt, echo things out :) Before move_uploaded_file line try outputting (echo or print) your $new_dir_name and $file_path variables and make sure their values are what they're supposed to be. In other words, make sure on the server side that your app actually passes the directory name and that the file path is generated correctly. As a side note, you should never upload files to directory names, supplied in a URL: this is very insecure. After retrieving the directory name from URL, make sure that it only contains safe characters (like alphanumeric).